# Not able to conda install, keep encountering Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to download Pytorch with conda intall, but it keep showning this error out "Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.",
I searched online that someone said by doing "conda update --all" or downgarding conda by "conda install conda=4.6.141" can solved the problem. But none of these works for me for some reason, conda update do have finish update, but still encountering same issue. While for downgrading conda=4.6.141, I am not able to install the older version of conda since I am encountering the same issue. Is there any other ways to solve this? (I am totally new to annaconda, so i might have missed install sth important) Can someone please give me some help or advice?

Comment: ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please ask an actual question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is a new bug in Conda, there is no reason to downgrade Conda, especially that low. Instead, the environment into which you are trying to install has likely become too complicated and so adding more packages is pushing the limits of what Conda can solve in a reasonable amount of time. Instead, it is better to create *new* environments each dedicated to projects/tasks.

In this case, try creating a new environment with PyTorch installed:

```bash
conda create -n pytorch -c pytorch pytorch
```

Alternatively, Mamba is a faster version of Conda and can often solve environments in seconds that might take hours with Conda. The only problem is being patient enough to install it into your Conda **base**:

```bash
conda install -n base -c conda-forge mamba

## now you can use `mamba` instead, e.g.,
mamba install -c pytorch pytorch
```